# Пробелы перед знаками препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Перед какими знаками препинания нужны пробелы в печатном тексте?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пробелы ставятся только **перед** тире, скобками и кавычками. В остальных случаях пробелы перед знаками препинания не ставятся.
Ставятся **после**: запятой, двоеточия, точки с запятой и всех знаков на конце предложения.

Answer (score 1):

Помимо названных знаков (тире, скобки и кавычки) пробел может появиться перед многоточием, если оно идет в начале предложения. 
Правда этот пробел будет относиться скорее к предыдущему знаку.
Ну и еще один казуистический случай. Пробел может появиться перед апострофом в иноязычных названиях, начинающихся с апострофа (такие есть в голландском, например).